# How can a program detect if it is running as a systemd daemon?

Tags: linux, systemd

Is there any way to detect in a program that it is run by systemd as a daemon?

systemd API

```
sd_booted()
```

is used to detected if the whole system is booted by systemd, but says nothing about the program itself.

Thanks

Comment: Check its `ppid` (parent process id) maybe?

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to *detect* that. I would instead have some program argument convention (e.g. assume that it has been started by `systemd` if you pass `--started-from-systemd`, and configure your systemd to pass that argument).

Comment: The `systemd` entry of `/proc/<pid>/cgroup` seems to be different for services run by systemd (I had a quick look on my raspberry pi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the parent process id and see whether that process is `systemd`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from systemd v232, an environment variable `INVOCATION_ID` is given to all processes started as (part of) a service unit. This is a nice trait from systemd and not any other service manager, so it can be used as a convenient way to detect systemd, but not necessarily reliable.

Personally I use this to disable timestamp in logging as systemd journal already does that.

Comment: I just ran `echo $INVOCATION_ID` in my regular terminal & I see an invocation id. Seems like systemd has launched my user session on my system, so this is might not necessarily work.

Comment: Indeed, this is not useful for systemd user sssion.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a magic environment variable in the daemon's service file and look for this variable.