# How to check if my program is indeed being run by systemd or is directly invoked?

Tags: c, linux, service, systemd

I have a program that is best suited to run as a (`systemd`) service in Linux. But the program has no checks to prevent it from the direct invocation (by the users). On the internet, some suggest checking for the environmental variable `$INVOCATION_ID`. This is from the man page of `systemd.exec`

> $INVOCATION_ID
>
> Contains a randomized, unique 128bit ID identifying each runtime cycle of the unit, formatted as 32 character hexadecimal string. A new ID is assigned each time the unit changes from an inactive state into an activating or active state, and may be used to identify this specific runtime cycle, in particular in data stored offline, such as the journal. The same ID is passed to all processes run as part of the unit.

But the environment variable `$INVOCATION_ID` doesn't seem to be something like a password which we can compute and verify that `systemd` is the one who started our program. If we are pessimistic about the scenario, a user can set the `$INVOCATION_ID` and pretend to be `systemd`. So what is the apt way of identifying whether `systemd` started our program or someone else?

Template-Code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
{
    if (/*program is not invoked by systemd*/) {
        fprintf(stderr, "this program is intended to be run as a service");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe something with [`getppid()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getppid.html) perhaps? Just *brainstorming* -- maybe it's a dead end, I have no idea.

Comment: You can check if the direct parent is systemd(pid=1)

Comment: Personally I am a fan of `systemd`, but adding tests like these are a bad idea. It should be up to the user how to start your service, be it directly, through `systemd` or another init system. Your program should only test if the actual features it needs are present, and not care about how it was started or what init system is used. Tests like these are the reason why Microsoft had to skip Windows 9, and why IExplorer has "Mozilla" in its user agent string.

Comment: @pmg That would be an interesting approach to consider. But the problem is we need to understand the dynamics of ``systemd``. If I ``grep`` the ``ps -aux`` output for ``systemd`` I can see multiple process, so which exactly started the process ( some can be obvious ignored like journal). And, ``systemd `` has different type of units, for all units ``systemd`` personally starts the process.or hand it over the some other ? (meaning should we look the immediate parent or parent before that?)

Comment: @Philippe So ``init`` process starts all systemd services ? As I was saying in my earlier comment, would it personally start all the services or may hand it over to someother ?

Comment: @HAL9000  In that point of view I can project my problem in other way. What is the best way to prevent the multiple instances of my application ? I think this is the environment check in my case. Off topic -- But I am really interested in the lines you quoted at the end. 1) Are there any technical reasons behind why windows 9 is skipped, it seems to be superstitious reasons when searched on net. 2) I see the mozilla string for Chrome also, I always think the reason to be for providing compatibility. Is it something different ?

Comment: @MohithReddy What we can say is if a process runs as a systemd service, then it's immediate parent is systemd (id=1).

Comment: @Philippe Then, that must be a solid approach to check the agent of invocation. I will get back to you after making sure of that programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a program detect if it is running as a systemd daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39368185/how-can-a-program-detect-if-it-is-running-as-a-systemd-daemon)